# requestCode parameter in startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

When you call [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), you also provide "int requestCode". How can you get that parameter in the started activity (to alter some initialization there)?

Or am I understanding the purpose of this parameter wrong and it only used to differentiate  calls in onActivityResult(), and started activity should be initialized based on Intents' action and extra bundle? I wonder where is it kept then, I suppose, it's still in Activity but private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thinkg, you have little misunderstanding. The requestCode is just used in your original activity to compare the result. All the parameters, you want to pass to the starting activity should be passed through extra's:

```
Intent.putExtra();
```

Comment: How can I avoid these double posts? :s

Comment: I was passing some parameters through extra bundle, but then saw requestCode and decided to put one main parameter there, but wasn't able to do it. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I think, its only to differentiate calls in onActivityResult(). If you want to send special initialization parameters, put them into the  extras of the calling intent.